# display tag for pagination without hitting database

Tags: displaytag

I am using display tag for pagination in jsp for displaying 10 records per page,But it hitting database everytime when we click on next or prev button .My tag is

```
<display:table  id="voucherauthorization" name="voucherAuthorizeDataList" pagesize="10" cellpadding="5px;"cellspacing="5px;" style="margin-left:100px;margin-button:20px;" requestURI="" >
```

I want records without hitting database , I am using records from list in jsp page. How can I do it?

Comment: which technology you are working and share what you have tried. then if you got stucked 

with some exact issue, we  will help you. Refer this link for asking proper questions 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You don't want to hit the DB? Well you always need to "hit" it at least once..... query the full table (or sql query result), bring it to a "middle" layer (server side) and cache it.... (some way to be reused later)... in forward http requests just "page query" this cached data......

Comment: There was bug in one of our jsp which shows data using displatag, with each paging request it was reloading data which was making it slow. Then we thought to filter out displaytag paging request and upon looking the pattern of displaytag paging request we found that it always starts with "d-", so by using this information you can filter out display tags paging request. Since we were using spring it was even easier as shown in below

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/displaytag-examples-tutorial-jsp-struts.html#ixzz3fHK7EBYC

Comment: i want hit database only once

Comment: or don't want hit database